# Using bubbles sort to sort ArrayList of (String, Int) to alphabetical order

Tags: java, arraylist, bubble-sort

I am trying to sort the babies in alphabetical order in the sortBabies using bubblesort but i unable to swap the position as the error came up as "The methods set(int, Baby) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments(int, string)". I set the name 1 and name 2 to string value so i am able to compare but now i am unable to swap the position.

```
import java.util.*;
public class BabyCilent {
static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<Baby> babies = new ArrayList<Baby>();
    
    /*for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Baby newBaby = getBaby();
        babies.add(newBaby);
    }*/
    
    //hardcode data so that dont need to keep entering
    
    Baby baby1 = new Baby("d", 4);
    Baby baby2 = new Baby("c", 3);
    Baby baby3 = new Baby("a", 1);
    Baby baby4 = new Baby("b", 2);
    babies.add(baby1);
    babies.add(baby2);
    babies.add(baby3);
    babies.add(baby4);
    
    int choice = 0;
    while(choice != 7){
       System.out.println("1. Print all the baby in the array list");
       System.out.println("2. Calculate the average age for all the baby");
       System.out.println("3. Remove the baby in the array listn");
       System.out.println("4. Add one more baby into the array list");
       System.out.println("5. Sort all the baby in alphabetical order");
       System.out.println("6. Output sorted baby to CSV file");
       System.out.println("7. Exit");
        choice = scanner.nextInt();
        if(choice == 1) {
            printAllBabies(babies);
        } 
        if(choice == 2) {
            calculateAveAge(babies);
        }
        if(choice == 3){
            removeBaby(babies);
        } 
        if(choice == 4){
            addInOneMoreBaby(babies);
        } 
        if(choice == 5) {
            sortBabies(babies);
        }
        if(choice == 6) {
            toCSVFile(babies);
        }
    }   
}

private static void sortBabies(ArrayList<Baby> babies) {
    boolean swap = true;
    while(swap) {
        swap = false;
        for(int i = 1; i < babies.size(); i++) {
            String name1 = babies.get(i-1).getName();
            String name2 = babies.get(i).getName();
            if(name1.compareTo(name2)>0) { //swap the two strings
                babies.set(i-1, name2);
                babies.set(i, name1);
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `ArrayList<Baby>` contains `Baby` objects. Why are you setting a `String`?

Comment: i am using the string to compare to the other string

Comment: That's fine :) My point is you should be setting the `Baby` objects, not their names.

Comment: but if i set is to
babies.set(i-1, babies[i]);
babies.set(i, babies[i-1]);
it will result in Multiple marker"The methods set(int, Baby) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments(int, string)" and  "The types of expression must be an array type but is resolved to ArrayList<Baby>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change the inner of your for loop in oder to set the elements to childs and not to string while swapping.

Your list is the type of `Baby` and you want to change elements in the list by the name of the baby. The problem with that is that the type of a name is a `String` and therefor missmatches the type `Baby`. In oder to fix this you can change the local variables to `Baby` instead of `String` and just use `getName()` in your if to compaire them as shown below:

```
for(int i = 1; i < babies.size(); i++) {
    Baby baby1 = babies.get(i-1);
    Baby baby2 = babies.get(i);
    if(baby1.getName().compareTo(baby2.getName())>0) { //swap the two strings
        babies.set(i-1, baby2);
        babies.set(i, baby1);
        swap = true;
    }
}
```